# Relation between pixels and blender unit and the grid floor?

Tags: 3d-view, units, 3d-manipulator

everyone I would like to know with fundaments , the relation between pixels and blenders's units  for  meshes over a custom grid's floor ( In my case I use the default grid floor).

I mean this steps (my target is create a tileable wall) .

1- I ve create a 640x640 grid in photoshop ( I ve configurated the grid lines
 by 64 pixels and 1 subdivision check the image below).
[image]

2 - Then I decided to go blender with my 640x640 image put it as background image .( The purpose is create tileable textures ) as you can see , the measure of the mesh is " 1m = x , 2m = y , 1m = z , and the scale is applyed to 1,1,1 in all axes) and as a remainder, the grid floor is by default (check it below)  .
  [image]

3 - so my conclution is false? 1 meter in blender is 64,64,64 pixels ( please let me know if I am wrong , consider the resolution of the image is 640 pixels with 72 ppi as in the first picture )

4 - I think my mesh is ok, at least ,it matches with the default grids and the image on the background.

Comment: This relationship is not constant, but dependent on the view zoom. The closer you are to the grid, the higher the number of pixels per blender unit, and vice versa. You can calculate this by looking through the camera. The entire camera view has the number of pixels you defined in the render settings. The closer the camera to the grid, the 'bigger' the becomes in the view.

Comment: so should I use to set the camera to some specifi resolution? in my case , I created a 2d grid in PS, then go in blende and by the default a cube with ( 1,1,1 bu or met) matches with my grid. how ever, the factor of the zoom shows me the major lines of the grid, but in certain distance (when I see the major line of the grid, most important line) I can able to certain the clue is ok, but I am not sure at all, ir there are a relationship between the topic.